# Removing a chromosome from a population?

Tags: java, arraylist, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to write a method to remove a chromosome from my population. The method I have written is below. I am getting an out of bounds error when I run the code. Population is constructed with an `ArrayList`. The `getChromosomeFitness` method returns an `int` value score. Can someone spot my error?

```
void removeWorst()
{   
  int worst = population.get(0).getChromosomeFitness();
  int temp = 0; 

  for(int i = 1; i < population.size(); i++)
  { 
    if (population.get(i).getChromosomeFitness() < population.get(worst).getChromosomeFitness())
    {
      worst = population.get(i).getChromosomeFitness();
      temp = i;
    }
  }
  Chromosome x = population.get(temp);
  population.remove(x);
}
```

Comment: Where does the out of bounds exception occur? Stacktrace?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 20, Size: 10
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
 at org.genetic.algorithm.Population.removeWorst(Population.java:33)

Comment: Stacktrace, does that help? Apologies, I am very new to programming

Comment: Please have a look at the stacktrace. It is very essential to understand reading them. This would even helped you to answer you question yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably change

```
if (population.get(i).getChromosomeFitness() < population.get(worst).getChromosomeFitness())
```

to

```
if (population.get(i).getChromosomeFitness() < worst)
```

Comment: +1 that makes sense. Although he should check that his list contains at least one item before starting.

Answer (score 0):

You don't assure that in this line `population` has an element with the index 0:

```
int worst= population.get(0).getChromosomeFitness();
```

Try to add this to your method:

```
void removeWorst() { 
   if (population.isEmpty()) {
      return;
   }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several potential problems in your code:

```
int worst= population.get(0).getChromosomeFitness();
```

you need to make sure that `population.isEmpty()` is false

```
population.get(worst).getChromosomeFitness()
```

same thing, you need to make sure that `(worst >= 0 && worst < population.size())`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems that you are getting the actual fitness rather than the object itself. The issue is with this line: `int worst= population.get(0).getChromosomeFitness();`. This is returning an integer value which is not related to the List's dimensions, as you said, it is the fitness of the chromozome, which could be well over the size of the list.

This should solve the problem:

```
void removeWorst()
{  
  int temp=0;   

  for(int i=1; i <population.size();i++)
  { 
    if (population.get(i).getChromosomeFitness() < population.get(temp).getChromosomeFitness())
    {
      temp=i;
    }
  }
  Chromosome x= population.get(temp);
  population.remove(x);
}
```

That being said, a probably neater way of doing this would be to use a custom comparator to sort the list and then simply remove the last element.

Comment: @bosra: You're welcome. If this solves your problem, then mark it so ;).

Answer (score -1):

Make sure population has something in it before trying to remove something from it?